# How to redirect to ASP.NET Web API route in same controller

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

With 2 routes as follows:

```
 [HttpGet("rules")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> GetRulesAsync(DateTime? businessDate = null, string 
 category = null) 
 {
    //...
 }


 [HttpGet("effectiveRules")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> GetEffectiveRulesAsync(DateTime? businessDate = null, string 
 category = null)
 {
    //want to redirect this to  [HttpGet("rules")]
 }
```

How can I redirect from second to the first API?
Tried `RedirectToRoute` un-successfully.
Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working demo to use `RedirectToAction`:

```
[Route("[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("rules")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetRulesAsync(DateTime? businessDate = null, string
 category = null)
        {
            //...
        }


        [HttpGet("effectiveRules")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetEffectiveRulesAsync(DateTime? businessDate = null, string
        category = null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("rules", new { businessDate = businessDate, category = category });
            //want to redirect this to  [HttpGet("rules")]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`return Redirect($"rules?businessDate={businessDate:yyyy-MM-dd}&category={category}");` worked.

Comment: You could also do the following: 

`return RedirectToAction(nameof(GetRulesAsync), new { businessDate = businessDate, category = category });`

The main advantage, in my opinion, is that you don't rely in the route the first method has. So you can change it and this will still work.